# Keep a variable in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a code like this:

```
def awnser():
    a = 1
    print(a)
    return (a)

def opzP():
    opz = "+"
    print(opz)
    print(a)
    return
```

I want to click at the first button and the command "awnser" run. But later I want to click on another button and the command "opzP" should run. But it doesnt store the variable a. How can I store that. Thank you for your help ^^

The Return command and so on...

```
def awnser():
    a = 1
    print(a)
    return (a)

def opzP():
    opz = "+"
    print(opz)
    print(a)
    return
```

Error-Message instead of the variable.

Comment: It is pointless to return anything from a Button's `command=` function - since you aren't calling the function yourself, and Tkinter doesn't do anything with the return value when it calls the function.  To have a value that persists past the end of the function, you have to explicitly store it someplace that will still be around after the function ends - typically a global variable, or an instance variable of some object that you've created.

Answer (score 1):

Witout using OOP, the easiest way to do so is to create a global variable:

```
a = 0
def do1():
    global a
    a=1
def do2():
    global a
    print(a)
```

But that's the bad way. Because it uses a global variable. The better way is:

```
class Funs:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def answer(self):
        self.a = 1
        print(self.a)
        return (self.a)
    def opzP(self):
        self.opz = "+"
        print(self.opz)
        print(self.a)
        return
obj = Funs()
Button(command=obj.answer).pack()
Button(command=obj.opzP).pack()
```

Hope that's helpful!