# Get tkinter askopenfilenames() function call result

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get a list of filenames on my local disk and use askopenfilenames() function and my scripts are:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames

window = Tk()
window.title('File Viewer')
lb=Label(window, text='Select your files:')
lb.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

def selectfiles():
    files = askopenfilenames(initialdir="D:\\Document", title="Select files")
    fileList = window.tk.splitlist(files)
    return fileList

btn = Button(window,text='Select Files',command=selectfiles)
btn.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)
window.mainloop()
```

But how can I get use of the file names after click the 'Select Files' button?

Comment: If you want to store the file names, use a `global` variable in the `selectfiles` function. If the storage is not important and you would like to perform certain actions on the file names, simply add the functionality in the `selectfiles` function

Answer (score 0):

`askopenfilenames` returns a list of filenames or empty list if cancel button selected
so you can access the filenames in the variable `files` in your code.
This will be a complete path to the file. You can do some splitting and get only the filename if that's what you are after

Comment: files variable is in the selectfiles function, but how to use it outside? I already returned the result. But how can I use the returned result in the Button’s command?

Comment: I normally create an empty list outside the function and copy the result to that. maybe someone can explain the correct way to do it. [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459343/keep-a-variable-in-tkinter)